Getting Dependency Issue with glassfish.jersey and Grizzly HttpServer (JDK 22)
I'm getting this particular error when trying to start Grizzly's HttpServer:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class org.glassfish.jersey.message.MessageProperties does not have member field 'java.lang.String JSON_MAX_STRING_LENGTH'
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature.configure(JacksonFeature.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:728)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:647)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:823)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:328)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:310)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:98)
    at org.golfballdm.Main.startHttpServer(Main.java:27)
    at org.golfballdm.Main.main(Main.java:33)

Process finished with exit code 1


From what I'm able to determine, this appears to be a dependency issue, but I'm at a loss as to which dependencies.
Main.java:
package org.golfballdm;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.golfballdm.ledgers.LedgerResource;
import org.golfballdm.census.CensusResource;

public class Main {
    public static final URI BASE_URI = URI.create("http://localhost:8080");

    // Starts Grizzly HTTP server
    public static HttpServer startHttpServer() {

        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(LedgerResource.class);
        config.register(CensusResource.class);
        // JacksonFeature for JAXB/POJO, for pure JSON, no need this JacksonFeature
        // config.register(JacksonFeature.class);

        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, config);  // <---- This line raises the error
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            final HttpServer server = startHttpServer();

            server.start();

            // shut down hook
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(server::shutdownNow));

            System.out.println("Application started.%nStop the application using CTRL+C");

            // block and wait shut down signal, like CTRL+C
            Thread.currentThread().join();

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}


The resource classes just have a GET operation returning a Hello World.
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.golfballdm</groupId>
    <artifactId>MomsDatabases</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Grizzly 2 HTTP Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey DI and core-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- add jackson as json provider -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
        <junit.version>5.4.0</junit.version>
        <jsonassert.version>1.5.0</jsonassert.version>
        <jersey.version>3.0.2</jersey.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>ledger-backend</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- JUnit 5 need at least 2.22.0 to support -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.golfballdm.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- copy project dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Finally, the mvn dependency:tree output:
[INFO] --- dependency:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ MomsDatabases ---
[INFO] org.golfballdm:MomsDatabases:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.inject:jakarta.inject-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.30.2-GA:compile
[INFO] \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.17.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.17.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.17.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.9:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations:jar:2.17.0:compile
[INFO]    \- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO]       \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.3:compile


This exact code did work last week (I reverted back to my master branch, which was working when I checked it in), hence I'm suspecting a dependency issue.
I'm expecting the webserver to start normally, and output some text to stdout.

According to the documentation, JSON_MAX_STRING_LENGTH was added in version 2.41 so I believe that you need to update your Jersey.

Changed jersey.version (line 55 in pom.xml) to 3.1.7, it still fails.  I'm assuming that 3.1.7 includes 2.41?

It appears that 3.1.7 includes 2.43. Are you still getting the same error that JSON_MAX_STRING_LENGTH does not exist?

(1) mvn dependency:tree  output: org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:3.0.2, (2)<version>${jersey.version}</version>, <jersey.version>3.0.2</jersey.version> (3) Is the content above not updated? Or has it been updated?

I did update <jersey.version> to 3.1.7, the error still happened until I changed the jackson-annotations dependency below.
Now I'm getting entirely new problems when I progress further, but that's far more code than is here.

Found a possible fix, or at least it displays the text I like, thanks for the insight, Abra.
Add the following dependency to pom.xml before jersey-media-json-jackson:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>

It was using 2.17.0 previously.
